# Warning: Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for QLRemotePreviewContentController

Tags: ios, ipad, swift, uidocumentinteraction, quicklook

I already found some solutions for this problem (it is caused because there is still an active animation).

But i am unable to solve that in my app when using a UIDocumentInteractionController on an iPad Application.

My ViewController looks like

MainViewController
-> ContainerView

In this ContainerView i have a Sidebar, and from this SideBar i would like to open an UIDocumentInteractionController.

I use a NSNotification, because this "MainViewController" should handle multiple Files from different Views.

So: (this is in my MainViewController)

```
func openFile(notification: NSNotification){

    fileUrl = notification.object as NSURL

    var documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: self.fileUrl!)
    documentInteractionController.delegate = self

    documentInteractionController.presentPreviewAnimated(false)
}

func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
    return self
}
```

But ill always get the following error:

*Warning: Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for QLRemotePreviewContentController*

I dont know why? There should be no animation, and if i open another (modal) window there is no Warning here.

If i use a delay (for example for 5 Seconds!) there is stil this Warning.

**Edit: Found out that i could be a Problem with my ContainerView. When i include "ViewWillDissapear" and "ViewDidDisappear" ill get the error here:**

```
view will dissappear

Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <QLRemotePreviewContentController: 0x7d35d400>

viww Did dissapaer
```

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is probably a bug in Apple's code as I have seen this warning as well even in their sample code. Please file a bug!

Comment: Thank you. That could be really just a stupig bug

Comment: I'm having a similar problem ..... have you filed a radar?

Comment: No sorry. i think this is really just a bug

Comment: **Thomas Deniau** Can you please provide me the apple code link if you have .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your application must be using a navigation controller. If that's the case, navigation controller must be the one to handle interaction for the preview, not the view controller within it.

Replacing your `return self` inside of `documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview` with `self.navigationController` should solve the problem. However, you need to safely unwrap `navigationController`. See the complete method below:

```
func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
    if let navigationController = self.navigationController {
        return navigationController
    } else {
        return self
    }
}
```

Cudos to @staxim for the Objective-C solution!

Comment: If you pass a navigation controller, it will push your view into the navigation stack, else if will present it modally. I wanted to remove that warning from the console, but instead it ruined my application. I have my navigation bar hidden and it makes it appear, broke all my constraints and so on… It is definitely just a warning.

Comment: @Crazyrems - yeah, this is a side effect. It didn't  brake my constraints but presented the view inside the navigation controller. This is not what I wanted, so I reverted it and just ignore the warning. However, some people will want the view to be presented within the navigation controller - hence the answer.

Comment: You can simply the code by using `return self.navigationController ?? self`.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this same problem, and it turned out to be an issue with the UINavigationController of my view.  I addressed it by changing the `documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview` method:

```
- (UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return [self navigationController];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the variable `documentInteractionController` only lives in the scope of the `openFile` function. Once the function is executed, the variable is garbage-collected and hence it is impossible to register the end appearance transition.

You can try promote the local variable to become a class variable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried this, but i receive the same error. Could this a problem because i have a ContainerView in my MainViewController?

Comment: I changed now my NSNotification and call now the function to open my UIDocumentInteraction from my DetailViewController (inside my ContainerView) - but still get the same "Warning".

Comment: I concur, the warning still appears for me too. The UIDocumentInteractionController is a class variable as well.